# Counting existing entries in an Azure storage table using a partial row key

Tags: c#, nosql, azure-table-storage

I'm storing some entities in an Azure storage table. I need to know the version number of each entity, and this comes from the number of entities already present with the same row key prefix.

For example, let's say the first entity has a row key of...

```
project_byPath_test-1.txt_1
```

Where the trailing `1` is the version number.

When a second entry is about to be stored, a row key prefix of...

```
project_byPath_test-1.txt
```

... is built, and I then count the number of entries which have this row key prefix, increment this result, and use this as the next version number. Consequently there will now be two entries in the table:

```
project_byPath_test-1.txt_1
project_byPath_test-1.txt_2
```

I now wish to store an entity named `test-2.txt`, so I build the following row key prefix...

```
project_byPath_test-2.txt
```

...and count the number of entries whose row key starts with this row key prefix using the following code...

```
tableClient.QueryAsync<ITableEntity>(e => e.PartitionKey == partitionKey && e.RowKey.CompareTo(rowKeyPrefix) >= 0)
```

I've also tried...

```
tableClient.QueryAsync<ITableEntity>($"PartitionKey eq '{partitionKey}' and RowKey ge '{rowKeyPrefix}'")
```

However, both of those queries returns a count reflecting the number of `test-1` entries in the table.

Am I correct in concluding that the `>=` / `ge` comparison applies to *each character within the string* rather than the string as a whole?

If so, can anyone suggest a way to achieve what I need here - *i.e.*, where the row key matches all characters specified, plus any others that may exist at the end of the string?

Would converting numerical characters to their string counterparts be a good idea - *i.e.*, `1` => `one`, `2` => `two`, *etc*., and using these in the row key?

**UPDATE:**
Here's a simple example of what I mean regarding the rowKey `>=` / `ge` querying: I have a single entry in the table, whose row key is `rowKey_2_1`, and this is returned when querying for `>= 'rowKey_1_'`.

[image]

So if it *is* performing a character-by-character comparison, would replacing each numerical digit with a single letter (for example, `0` => `J`, `5` => `E`, and `9` => `A`) be a good solution? *I.e.*, instead of using the row key...

```
project_byPath_test-1.txt_1
```

... I instead use...

```
project_byPath_test-I.txt_1
```

... where `1` has been replaced by `I`? This way, I could prevent the query `>= 'project_byPath_test-2.txt'` counting the row key `project_byPath_test-1.txt_1` because the query would then become `>= 'project_byPath_test-H.txt'` and it would be compared against an existing row key of `project_byPath_test-I.txt_1`.